# How execute synchronicity in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to do somethink on array: skinydobazy after add new param check.

```
skinydobazy.forEach(function(klucz,index) {   
    getPrice(data.prices[0]).then(function(results) {

            var price = results.skinData.wep.median_price;
            if(price > 1)
            klucz.check = 1;

            console.log('HERE');

        });
  }); // end foreach 


  console.log(skinydobazy); //do sth after foreach
```

(after foreach loop) I want to do somethink with updateted skinydobazy. But I have a problem. Because first display skinydobazy, but should "HERE" and after should display skinydobazy.

Is any solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `forEach`, you can produce an array of Promises. You can then subscribe to the completion of all Promises in that array using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
Promise.all(skinydobazy.map(function(klucz, index) {
  // Return the Promise that resolves on .then(fn)
  return getPrice(data.prices[0]).then(function(results) {

    var price = results.skinData.wep.median_price;
    if (price > 1)
      klucz.check = 1;

    console.log('HERE');

    // Resolve Promise with results
    return results;
  });
}).then(function(allResults) {
  // allResults will be an array of results
  console.log(skinydobazy);
});
```